# How to set an int array to another int array

Tags: java, arrays

How could I set an `int[]` array to another `int[]`?

Example:

```
int array[] = new int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array2[] = new int[]array;
```

or

```
int array[] = new int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array2[] = array[];
```

But it doesn't work!

Can somebody tell me how?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But why downvote? I just wanted to know it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use

```
array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
```

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

> **copyOf**
>
> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with zeros (if
> necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
> are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
> contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
> but not the original, the copy will contain 0. Such indices will exist
> if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the
> original array.

Answer (score 4):

Why didn't you try with the most obvious:

```
int[] array2 = array;
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one :3

Comment: But note that this does not make a copy of the array. Both variables will point at the same array, so changes in one will be seen in the other. If you want a copy, use `java.util.Arrays.copyOf` .